# Applescript loop through result of "ls" with "do shell script"

Tags: macos, unix, applescript

I have selected a list of files in Applescript using:

```
set variableName to do shell script "cd /; cd dev/; ls tty.usb*"
```

When I print out variableName, it shows this list:

file1
file2

From here, I want to loop through each of them using:

```
repeat with theItem in variableName
   display dialog theItem
end repeat
```

Instead of showing "file1" and "file2" one by one, it shows "f, i, l, e, 1," and so forth.

How can I loop the list to get a complete file name?

Comment: Notice you can do it entering this into the terminal: `find /dev/ -name "tty.usb*" -exec osascript -e 'display dialog "{}"' \;`

Comment: Set myList to very paragraph of variableName. then you have to loop through each element of myList.

Comment: @Yoric Thanks! It works like charm in terminal, yet I intend to do this in applescript. Is there anyway to convert this code into applescript?

Comment: @pbell do you mean this: "set testList to paragraph of the variableName"? It shows this result: "Can’t get paragraph of "my ls output".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful responses! I have found out the solution.

```
set variableName to do shell script "find /dev/tty.usb*"
display dialog variableName

set testArray to paragraphs of the variableName

repeat with theItem in testArray
   display dialog theItem
end repeat
```

By using paragraphs, I'm able to split by newline and covert the result into a list.

Comment: And you're using `find` rather than `ls` which is much more preferable if you're going to be utilising the results.